# how to write js function to get input value when click button

Tags: javascript

i have several class="items" that include input and button, and i want to click button and identify whether siblings input has value or not.

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var $this = elem.tagName;
  var val = $this.siblings('input[type=text]').val();
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick()">button1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick()">button2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick()">button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$this = elem.tagName` will make a variable that is a string. `$this.siblings` seems to be trying to treat it as a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass object `this` to the function and get the previous element with [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) from that element.

**Please Note:** `val()` is jQuery method, the equivalent JavaScript property is `value`

```js
function onClick($this) {
  var val = $this.previousElementSibling.value;
  if(val == ''){
      console.log('no input');
  }else{
     console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
    <button onclick="onClick(this)">Search 1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
    <button onclick="onClick(this)">Search 3</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
    <button onclick="onClick(this)">Search 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id of input tag from onClick function.

```
function onClick(elem) {
  var $this = $(elem);
  var val = $this.val();
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}

<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick('#keywordSearch1')">button1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick('#keywordSearch2')">button2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick('#keywordSearch3')">button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ugh, why pass the ID of the element? If you change the ID, you now have to change two pieces of code to ensure it still works. Also, you would be clicking on a button and initiating a seach on the entire page to find out what you clicked on. There are at least three different ways to *directly* get the element that was clicked on, without having to look it up in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

First of all, your `onClick` function has a `elem` parameter, but you never pass it in. To do that, you need to use `onclick="onClick(this)"` in the HTML, that way when the `onClick` function is called, you would get the current element as the argument.

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var $this = elem.tagName;
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button1</button>
</div>
```

Second problem is that you are taking `elem.tagName` which would be a *string* and treating it as if it's a jQuery object.

You should either include jQuery and use that as appropriate. You also need to specify `type="text"` in order to use the `input[type=text]` selector:

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var $this = $(elem); //< -- wrap the element in a jQuery wrapper
  var val = $this.siblings('input[type=text]').val();
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button1</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can do the same without jQuery using pure JavaScript with minor changes to get the same effect:

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  //get the parent
  var parent = elem.parentNode;
  
  var val = parent
    .querySelector('input[type=text]')//search the parent's children to simulate sibling searching
    .value; //the non-jQuery way to get the value
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button1</button>
</div>
```

Finally, having an in-line `onclick` specified in HTML is generally a bad idea. The preferred way is to attach event listeners via JS. In jQuery, you can do that using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var $this = $(elem);
  var val = $this.siblings('input[type=text]').val();
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}

//attach the click listerner
$('button').on('click', function() {
  onClick(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button>button1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
  <button>button3</button>
</div>
```

Or in pure JavaScript:

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var parent = elem.parentNode;
  
  var val = parent
    .querySelector('input[type=text]')
    .value;
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}

//attach the click listerner to each element
var buttons  = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    onClick(this);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button>button1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="text" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
  <button>button3</button>
</div>
```

Do note, that if you are attaching the event listener directly, then you can even omit passing in `this` as an argument:

- in jQuery : `$("button").on("click", onClick)`
- in plain JS, it's a similar situation, you would do `button.addEventListener("click", onClick)`

Once you do that, you have more options at your disposal:

- a function executed as an event listener will have the `this` context set as the element that it was initiated from. So, you can directly bind the listener

  - in jQuery: `var $this = $(this)`.
  - in plain JS: `var parent = this.parentNode`
- the event listener will also be passed in the `event` that the listener responded to. From there you can find the original target that was clicked:

```js
function onClick(event) {
  var elem = event.target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes to get the element values.

1. Use previous Element Sibling, as the element is before the button.
2. Provide the current context in the `onclick` method `onClick(this)`
3. You are not using the jQuery so the `.siblings` won't work, as this is available in the jQuery Lib

```js
function onClick(elem) {
  var val = elem.previousElementSibling.value;;
  //var val = $this.siblings('input[type=text]').val();
  if (val == '') {
    console.log('no input');
  } else {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
  <button onclick="onClick(this)">button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I have posted my own. It took me long due to the additional text I was writing. Otherwise, I could have posted it before you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise your to use [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) instead manually add onClick to each button. And also You can easily use [jQuery#prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to determine direct sibling.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.items>button', (e) => {
 const siblingInputValue = $(e.target).prev().val();
 debugger;
 console.log('Sibling input value: ' + siblingInputValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch1" placeholder="">
    <button>btn 1</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch2" placeholder="">
    <button>btn 2</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <input type="" name="" id="keywordSearch3" placeholder="">
    <button>btn 3</button>
</div>
```